# Node-red crash while trying to login

Tags: node-red

I tried to implement basic authentification in my node-red instance by following the guide : http://nodered.org/docs/security.html

Bellow the config i put in **settings.js** i crypted the password using the **node-red-admin** tool :

```
 adminAuth: {
   type: "credentials",
   users: [{
       username: "admin",
       password: "$2b$08$NoR7UKTA44tg6RGgj8j/kOUTsCJzbFhg2lIQ.fnxyYCW1py8e2JKi",
       permissions: "*"
   }]
},
```

After restarting the node red i the server crash if i put the correct credentials.

I tried to unable the logs but i didn't get anything.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What logs did you check? The Node-RED logs or the system logs? If it's actually crashing, it will be logged somewhere I'd imagine.

Comment: Also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58605615/edit) the question with details of what version of Node-RED, NodeJS and what platform you are running on (as this may help direct you to where the logs are) and how you are starting Node-RED

Comment: thanks for your answer, i posted the complete console log. You can see its just stopping like that.

Comment: Is that a just a cat of a log file, or is that the raw output from the `node-red` command? (also in future please post actual text & format it, not images as they are impossible to search)

Comment: Its the output of the node-red command with level "trace"